# Why would XNA not consistantly get TUIO Data from CCV?

Tags: c#, xna, vision

I'm using TUIO_Sharp, which is the TUIO API for C#.  I've included the TUIO assembly in an XNA project that I'm working on.  I've made a surface interface that works nicely (at a total cost of about $40!) and Community Core Vision (a computer vision bit of software) works famously with it.  I know that CCV is transmitting data correctly, as the TUIO Sharp demo works and receives the data and does all that it is supposed to do.

But, when I create the TUIO client and do all the requisite things as described in the documentation it doesn't work.  In fact, all I have it doing is changing the background color when the table surface is touched.

```
using all_the_xna_stuff;
using TUIO;
  namespace Test
  {
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, TuioListener
    {
        private int port;
    ...
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        port = 3333;
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        Client = new TuioClient(port);
        Client.addTuioListener(this);
        Client.connect();

        base.Initialize();


    }
    ...
    public void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj)
    {
        if (backgroundColor.R < 240)
        {
            backgroundColor.R += 10;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your `addTuioObject` method to be sure it's not getting called?

Comment: One issue could be that because XNA runs a game loop the `Client` doesn't have a chance to do anything.

Comment: I think you're right, George.  TUIO has a built in TUIOTIME class that works quite separately from the XNA GameTime class.  I'm wondering if I could make the TUIO stuff happen using GameTime rather than TUIOTIME.